# Connecting to CORS enabled API from ASP.NET MVC Model C# Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have following API where the CORS origin is enabled for abc.com

API - www.testapi/api/product/2/get

Client Domain - abc.com

I consume the API in C# code of ASP.Net MVC Application (ABC.com). Will my API get to know abc.com domain & allow the API call?

Comment: Which is your API here?

Comment: API - www.testapi/api/product/2/get

Comment: Are you calling the API from C# code or JavaScript code?

Comment: I consume the API in C# code of ASP.Net MVC Application. Let's say productModel.cs

Comment: Server to server calls to API will not have any CORS... Also your API will not know the domain of abc.com in server to server calls. CORS and domain come in picture when you are calling you from JavaScript code which runs in browser.